# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception using scanner for reading the element of an array

Tags: java

I want to print an array in matrix form by taking input from the user. I came to this code but this code throwing an exception of `ArrayIndexOutOfBound`. I tried hard but I am unable to come to any conclusion so please help me out.

Here's the code:

```
System.out.println("Enter the row i.e no. of array in x");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter the size of array");

int y[] = new int[n];
for (int i = 1; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
int z[][] = new int[n][];
for (int i = 1; i < y.length; i++) {
    z[i] = new int[y[i]];
}
System.out.println("Enter the elements of array");
for (int i = 1; i < z.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < z[i].length; j++) {
        z[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
System.out.println("Matrix is");
for (int i = 1; i < z.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < z[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(z[i][j]);
        System.out.print("\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: It may be useful to add the stack trace for the exception you are seeing and indicate the line where it happens.

Comment: Also as a general matter, test after writing little bits of code at a time. Unit testing preferred, but even just a quick run with a print statement. This way you know where the error is.

Comment: what inputs cause ArrayOutOfBoundsException?

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid.

```
int y[] = new int[n];
for (int i = 1; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Arrays are 0-indexed:

```
int y[] = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

You need to change all your iterations.

Comment: +1 but this still won't cause an exception as the indices are in bound

Comment: @giorashc true, hard to tell without the stack trace. The problem might happen because one of the X[0] values is not properly initialized.

Comment: Maybe this is semantics, but I would say this is valid...but a bug.  Starting at 1 just leaves out the first element. Just because arrays are 0-indexed, that doesn't mean you must iterate from the very beginning to use them in general. Of course, the OP intended to do so in this case.

Comment: if I write for(i=1;i<=y.length;i++) than is it possible?